# C print 2D array elements in ascending or descending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array in which many elements are zero. For example:

```
int array[10][10];
memset(array, 0, 100 * sizeof(int));
array[0][0] = 3;
array[2][8] = 5;
array[4][0] = 4;
```

How could I print the **non-zero** (only positive) elements in descending (or ascending) order. I was thinking about something like this:

```
int xpos, ypos;
while (getMaximumInArray(array, &xpos, &ypos))
    {
    printf("x=%i y=%i val=%i\n", xpos, ypos, array[xpos][ypos]);
    array[xpos][ypos] = 0; // set to 0 to make sure we find the next biggest value.
    }
```

However this makes me loop through the array many times (as much as there are non-zero elements). Would there be a better (ie less operations) way to do this?

**EDIT** : I forgot to specify that I would like to use the positions in my output; so I need not only the sorted values; but also their indices...

Comment: This doesn't look like C++. What language are you writing in?

Comment: this is c; I'm writing mixed code... C will do fine for me, but even a mix of both is possible... afaik C-code can still be used in .cpp files.

Comment: I like to keep high performance in my code; so I tend to convert some parts of my code to C; since iterators etc. tend to be slower.

Comment: Do a single loop to get all non-zero elements, and store them in a second uni-dimensional array. Then sort this second array.

Comment: Debug iterators perform bounds checking, a common source of bugs. Optimized iterators can be just as fast as C - did you check the assembly?

Comment: why the downvotes please?

Comment: @ChrisMaes If you seek a `c` answer, then put a `c` tag. Who cares where do you use it. `c++` answer would look entirely different than `c`-one.

Comment: @luk32 ok, I removed the C++ tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to make this more efficient is to simply sort the values. Sorting - or copying while sorting - has runtime complexity of `O(n log n)` which is an improvement over your `O(n*n)`. An easy and efficient way to do that is to copy the non-zero values to a `std::multiset` and then iterate through it.

---

Update regarding your edit:

No problem. Simply store an object that contains the value and the indices in the set and supply a comparison functor that uses only the value.

Comment: I was guessing that your answer allowed me to do what I need. I'll try it out first...

Comment: @ChrisMaes you can do this with array and `std::sort` just as well. It's hard to guess which would be faster without profiling. I prefer my approach due to simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You could create new array and then sort it.
For example:

```
int array[10][10];
array[0][0] = 3;
array[2][8] = 5;
array[4][0] = 4;

int positive[100];

int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        if(array[i][j] > 0){
            positive[k++] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
sort(positive, positive + k);
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
     printf("%d", positive[i]);
}
```

Comment: 97 values of `array` are uninitialized, not 0. Also you look for positive numbers while OP asks for non-zero values.

Comment: I did specify positive numbers in my case... and he is not using the uninitialized values...

Comment: Probably `std::sort`.

Comment: sorry, there are several sort function, for example qsort in stdlib.h (for C language) or std::sort for C++. You could choose something.

Comment: what about 97 values, yes this is a good memory optimization, you can iterate over source array twice: firstly, to know how many non-zero numbers in it, then create an array, and secondary copy elements from source array to new array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which is nice. You just fixed the sort (whence the upvote), but I forgot to mention that I still need the indices

Comment: Then allocate a 1-D array of a structure that stores the row and column with the non-zero value and sort the 1-D array by the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this. Denis Gavrus proposed using an array, which is fine, but you can use a vector if you want to be more memory efficient:

Also, if you need to keep your values and  their position, you'll need to store them in a struct/class (the *ELEMENT* struct), which will need a separate comparison class/function.

Here is the container and the comparison function:

```
struct ELEMENT{ ///Containing the value and the coordinates
    int val, i, j;
};

bool cmp(ELEMENT a, ELEMENT b){
    return a.val<b.val;
}
```

And here is the code that processes your data:

```
const int L=10; ///In case you want to modify the matrix dimensions
int array[L][L]; ///A really bad name for anything
vector<ELEMENT> v; ///The vector containing the sorted values

for(int i=0; i<L; i++)  ///Initialize the matrix with 0
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        array[i][j]=0;

array[0][0] = 3;    ///Your values...
array[2][8] = 5;
array[4][0] = 4;

for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        if(array[i][j]!=0)
            v.push_back({array[i][j], i, j});   ///Insert into v the non-zero values and the coordinates

sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);

for(ELEMENT i:v)///Your output
    printf("%d at position (%d, %d)\n",i.val, i.i, i.j);
```

Also, you could use a priority queue:

The comparison class for the priority queue:

```
class cmp{  ///Containing the functor for the priority queue
public:
    bool operator()(ELEMENT a, ELEMENT b){
        return a.val<b.val;
    }
};
```

The code that does stuff:

```
const int L=10; ///In case you want to modify the matrix dimensions
int array[L][L]; ///A really bad name for anything
priority_queue<ELEMENT, vector<ELEMENT>, cmp> v; ///The priority queue containing the sorted values

for(int i=0; i<L; i++)  ///Initialize the matrix with 0
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        array[i][j]=0;

array[0][0] = 3;    ///Your values...
array[2][8] = 5;
array[4][0] = 4;

for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        if(array[i][j]!=0)
            v.push({array[i][j], i, j});   ///Insert into v the non-zero values

for(; !v.empty(); v.pop())
    printf("%d at position (%d, %d)\n",v.top().val, v.top().i, v.top().j);
```